# Apache Camel File Queue Requires Directory Write Permissions For NOOP Consumer?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a simple NOOP file consumer configured in camel as follows:

```
file:///tst?delay=10000&idempotent=false&include=fileMatch&noop=true
```

Normally the user running the camel application will not have write permissions to /tst, however does have read and write permissions to /tst/fileMatch. Unfortunately I'm finding that camel won't even poll for the file unless it has write permissions to /tst.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shouldn't ask questions when I'm this tired. The reason that this doesn't work ([as clearly stated in the component description](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html)) is that the default `readLock` strategy is `markerFile` (which needs to write the marker file in the directory). By changing this to `readLock=fileLock` I no longer need write permissions on the directory to read the file as the file system lock is placed on the file being read.

The working URI is:

```
file:///tst?delay=10000&idempotent=false&include=fileMatch&noop=true&readLock=fileLock
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the last answer, the camel file component had a relevant change:

> Notice from Camel 2.10 onwards the read locks changed, **fileLock** and
>   rename will also **use a markerFile as well**, to ensure not picking up
>   files that may be in process by another Camel consumer running on
>   another node (eg cluster). This is only supported by the file
>   component (not the ftp component).

Hence, in Camel 2.10 or above, you still need write permission to use readLock=fileLock. You can use `readLock=none`, with the obvious impact that there will not be a read lock.